# Does ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) preserves the order?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am planning to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` in select queries which do not have the any proper data columns to use in order-by clause.

Generally, `ROW_NUMBER()` will be ordered exactly the same with each execution if I use `ORDER BY` with valid column data. By using `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`, what will be `ROW_NUMBER()` order, will it change with each execution?

If order is not changing (tested from my side, order is not changing), is it good use?

Comment: That you expect a certain order would seem to imply that in fact there _is_ some order you have in mind.  You might want to add sample data to your question.  Not sure about the contract with `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`, but I would guess that you should not rely on it.

Comment: I don't have order in datawise. Only reason i am using ROW_NUMBER() function to pick data in batches (500 at a time) by using rownumber order.

Comment: Well it either uses some order or it doesn't; but none of that even matters, because in either case as the underlying data changes, so would the top N records being returned per group.

Comment: in my case, every day whole table replace with new data and as i can't use ORDER BY and want to use ROW_NUMBER()OVER () function to select  records in batches by using rownumbers. if ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) gives same order with each execution so my code can pick data without worrying about duplicates

Comment: In MySql 8.0 that `ORDER BY` isn't required. So you can do `row_number() over ()`.  The `row_number() over (order by (select null))`  is a work-around for MS Sql Server, which requires an `ORDER BY` a non-literal in the ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause you may get different `ROW_NUMBER()` for a specific row on different executions. Same with `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` which is either a hack to bypass the syntax requirements or a syntactic sugar; it does not enforce an order.

You are getting same results, yes, ***but there is no guarantee***.

Answer (score 4):

You have tagged with question MySQL.  But you have used unnecessarily arcane syntax.  MySQL supports both these constructs:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL)
```

In both cases, you are saying "I don't care what the order is".  **A very important corollary:**  "I don't care if the result is the same on two different runs of the same query.

To be honest, `ROW_NUMBER()` is not guaranteed to return the same result when the `ORDER BY` keys are the same.  Why?  Because SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "default" ordering to fall back on.

Your particular syntax is a work-around for SQL Server, because that database requires an `ORDER BY` clause for `ROW_NUMBER()` *and* SQL Server does not allow constants in the `ORDER BY`.

Of course, *exactly* the same conditions hold in that database -- or in any other database.

The simple answer is:  No, you cannot assume the result will be in the same order if you run the same query again.

Answer (score -1):

Execution of ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) always returns the same order as the execution of a normal table.

Comment: . . This answer is simply wrong.  I would recommend that you just delete it.

Comment: Hi Gordon, 
Please let me know the reason why I delete it because I practically tested it on different tables and the result will be the same as the execution of the normal table.

Comment: . . You may *observe* this in the queries you run, but as far as I know, Microsoft does not guarantee this.