# How do I enable ordinals from the STRING_SPLIT function in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to use the STRING_SPLIT function in Microsoft SQL Server 2019. The function works, if I only put in two arguments, but since I want to extract a specific element from the string, I would like to enable ordinals.
When I add the third argument to the STRING_SPLIT function it returns

> Msg 8144, Level 16, State 3, Line 5 Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT
> has too many arguments specified.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, since hovering over the STRING_SPLIT function clearly states that the function can take a third argument as an int.

My SQL code is as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT('[Control Structure].Root.NP_02.ABC01_02_03.Applications.Prototype.Control Modules.ABC060V.ABC060VXFR2','.',1)
WHERE ORDINAL = 4
```

Comment: The third argument is currently only available in Azure SQL Database. Not SQL Server 2019.

Comment: The feature is also planned for SQL Server 2022. Azure SQL Database is ahead of the boxed version.

Answer (score 18):

You can't enable it, since it is not available in SQL Server 2019 (and is almost certainly not going to be back-ported there).

The problem is that SSMS has IntelliSense / tooltips coded without conditional logic based on version, and the code is ahead of the engine. Currently the functionality is only available in Azure SQL Database, Managed Instance, and Synapse.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql):

> The *enable_ordinal* argument and `ordinal` output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only).

Some more background:

- [Trusting STRING_SPLIT() order in Azure SQL Database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7039/stringsplit-function-azure-sql-database-ordinal-position/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

What you can do instead is create your own inline table-valued UDF that provides the same type of ordinal output (and make it return the same output as `STRING_SPLIT` to make it easy to change later). There are many variations on this; here's one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered
(
    @List       nvarchar(max),
    @Delimiter  nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT value = Item ,
      ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), 
    FROM (SELECT Number, Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
      CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
GO
```

Another simpler way would be to use JSON, which I forgot I even wrote recently in [this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7034/sql-split-string-with-openjson/?utm_source=AaronBertrand):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered
(
  @List      nvarchar(max),
  @Delimiter nchar(1)
)
RETURNS table WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT value, ordinal = [key]
    FROM OPENJSON(N'["' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, N'","') + N'"]') AS x
  );
GO
```

Also, if you're just trying to get the last ordinal in a (1-)4-part name and each part is <= 128 characters, you can use `PARSENAME()`:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(512) = N'here is one.here is two.and three.and four';

SELECT p1 = PARSENAME(@str, 4),
       p2 = PARSENAME(@str, 3),
       p3 = PARSENAME(@str, 2),
       p4 = PARSENAME(@str, 1);
```

Output:

| p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| here is one | here is two | and three | and four |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e492b658e6274cc61bdfb2ffbc62ca6)

Comment: Love the OpenJson solution. Didn't know that existed. I could use that a lot.

Comment: +1 for the `OPENJSON()` solution, thank you as always! One thing I noticed is it gets mad at certain characters like double quotes `"`. Is there a proper way to escape that in the `OPENJSON()` function or is my best bet to replace them with a placeholder character and replace it back after?

Comment: @J.D. In many scenarios, `STRING_ESCAPE()` will do. https://dbfiddle.uk/YGPEpskI

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ah, learned another function today. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

We can sort of cheat our way around ordinal as our order by using the current order instead. Keep in mind that the default order for STRING_SPLIT is non-deterministic:

[STRING_SPLIT() reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string. You can override the final sort order by using an ORDER BY clause on the SELECT statement, for example, ORDER BY value or ORDER BY ordinal.

```
DECLARE @object as nvarchar(500) = 'test_string_split_order_string'
select
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum
from STRING_SPLIT(@object, '_')
```

Comment: To point out that order by (SELECT NULL) does not guarantee results to be ordered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644259/7137090

Comment: I ended up writing a function that's pretty similar to this and just called it `string_split_ordinal`, with parameters `@input nvarchar(max), @delimiter nchar(1)`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's XML/XQuery allow to implement very easy tokenization of a string.

XML/XQuery data model is based on *ordered sequences*.

It allows to retrieve any token based on its position is a string of tokens.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tokens VARCHAR(256) = '[Control Structure].Root.NP_02.ABC01_02_03.Applications.Prototype.Control Modules.ABC060V.ABC060VXFR2'
    , @separator CHAR(1) = '.'
    , @pos INT = 4;

SELECT c.value('(/root/r[sql:variable("@pos")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS token
FROM (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(@tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+
|    token    |
+-------------+
| ABC01_02_03 |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another way (with ';' as delimiter)

```
create function dbo.split_string_ord
(
    @sentence nvarchar(max)
)
returns table
as
return(
    with first_word(ordinal,word,sentence) as (
    Select
        1 as ordinal,
        substring(@sentence+';',1,charindex(';',@sentence+';',1)-1) as word,
        substring(@sentence+';',charindex(';',@sentence+';',1)+1,LEN(@sentence+';')-charindex(';',@sentence+';',1)+1) as sentence
    union all
    Select
        ordinal + 1 as ordinal,
        substring(sentence,1,charindex(';',sentence,1)-1) as word,
        substring(sentence,charindex(';',sentence,1)+1,LEN(sentence)-charindex(';',sentence,1)+1) as sentence
    from
        first_word
    where
        sentence != ''
    )
    Select
        ordinal,
        word
    from
        first_word
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an ordinal by returning to the original value being split, finding the charindex() and applying row_number() with appropriate partition and group by.

```
declare @string varchar(100) = 'car,dog,guitar,food'

select *, charindex(value, @string) Orderer
, row_number() over (order by charindex(value, @string)) Ordinal
from (
select * 
from string_split(@string, ',')
) x
order by charindex(value, @string)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTable (Value varchar(max), Ordinal int identity(1,1))
```

Now just insert the values into that table.

```
INSERT INTO tmpTable (Value)
SELECT * FROM string_split('this.is.a.test', '.')
```

You'll end up with a table with an ordinal value populated.

```
SELECT * FROM tmpTable
```