# Transposing a single column table to row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm feeling horribly stupid. I can't for the life of me figure out how to transpose the simplest of all cases from a column to a row. All pivot/unpivot whatever examples I find shows complex cases with aggregation and what not, but how the heck does one just transform this:

| value |
| --- |
| a |
| b |

into this:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |

It should be easy??

Comment: Hint: `MIN`/`MAX`.

Comment: All methods are more complex than you'd hope as you need a way to say what content should go in which column...  I'm guessing you want 1 row in your result, with a column per row from the original table.  In your example you have 2 rows (in the source data); will you always have 2 rows (/a fixed number of rows), or could that change each run?  If the latter, dynamic SQL may be needed

Comment: assuming you do actually have > 2 rows you need to assign a row numbering and then pivot using that. the row number is unique so min/max just ends up projecting the single value that exists for that row number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a table like this:

```sql
create table so73413517 (
  value char(1)
)

insert so73413517(value) values('a'),('b') 
--,('c') -- etc.
```

If you will only ever want to return 1 row with 2 columns the [max/min](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73413580/361842) solution works best.

If you want 1 row but with more columns (but a fixed number) you can use `row_number` to give each row a unique, consecutive number, then you can do something like this

```sql
select max(case when r = 1 then value end) value1
, max(case when r = 2 then value end) value2
--, max(case when r = 3 then value end) value3 --etc.
from
(
    select row_number() over (order by value) r
    , value
    from so73413517
) x
```

Or

```sql
select [1], [2] 
--, [3] -- etc.
from
(
    select row_number() over (order by value) r
    , value
    from so73413517
) x
pivot
(
  max(value) for r in 
  (
    [1], [2]
    --,[3] --etc.
  )
) pvt
```

If you don't know how many rows are in the source/columns you want in your output, use dynamic SQL to create a column for each row (i.e. this uses the same logic as the pivot example above, but generates the query for the appropriate number of results:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 

; with cte as (
    select count(1) rowNum from so73413517
    union all 
    select rowNum -1 from cte where rowNum  > 1
)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ',','') + quotename(rowNum) 
from cte 
order by rowNum

set @sql = 'select ' + @sql + '
from
(
    select row_number() over (order by value) r
    , value
    from so73413517
) x
pivot
(
  max(value) for r in (' + @sql + ')
) pvt'

exec (@sql)
```

### WARNING

That said; the above clearly isn't nice code... and normally that's a sign that something's wrong.  If you're having to wrangle data in this way, look into whether you have the option to redesign your schema, or approach your underlying requirement with a different solution.  If you're not sure how to do that feel free to ask on here.

i.e. This question feels like it may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/199916).

### Update

From the discussion in the comments, maybe `ParseName` would help.

```
declare @data nvarchar(128) = 'a,b,c'
 select parsename(tokenised, 3) value1
 , parsename(tokenised, 2) value2
 , parsename(tokenised, 1) value3
 from (select replace(@data, ',','.')) x(tokenised)
```

Note: [ParseName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is used to split apart `instance.catalog.schema.table` formatted names, so can only work with up to 4 x 128 char strings separated by dots.

More info on that trick and other options for your particular use case here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862904/361842

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed something this simple would be built in to SQL Server ready to use.  More specifically I'm trying to convert the result of a STRING_SPLIT to a single row (e.g. `select * From STRING_SPLIT ('a,b,c', ',', 1)` . I know the number of columns that will be needed, so this will do fine without the dynamic SQL.

Comment: @mattboy - in that case you should pivot on the `ordinal` column and not bother row numbering

Comment: @mattboy it would be nice; but generally SQL assumes a fixed number of known columns as with most interactions that's important (e.g. aside from ad-hoc queries in SSMS most queries will come from programs which would identify data by column name... and for scenarios like yours you'd implement the logic in the client app's code rather than using SQL for that manipulation.

Comment: Ps. See update for another solution... I've no experience with `ordinal` as it looks like that's an Azure SQL feature; but it sounds worth a go if you're on an Azure SQL db.

Comment: The ParseName solution is perfect for my case, thanks for that!

Comment: @JohnLBevan - yes it is currently Azure only and the SQL given above already returns it https://i.stack.imgur.com/8klaw.png

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte(val)as
(
  select 'a' union all
  select 'b'
)
select
  min(val) col1,max(val)col2
   from cte
```

Just for your example